# Oracle UCM won't show original pdf file name

Tags: oracle, file, rename, oracle-ucm

I've been working with Oracle UCM.

All I have to do is to scan some documents, copy those pdf files in the Oracle Content Server, and then I should have access to the site and be able to search those files with their respectives names.

So far so good, but here's where things comes ugly.

Once I'm done searching one file, the UCM site doesn't show me the real name, the one that I gave to the scanned pdf. The site shows the name "sitios" ( "sites" in spanish, I'm in a latin country)  instead of the name I gave it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Usually files will  be stored in two places in file system .
One will be vault location . File will be stored as it is .

Usually file name will be

> dID.extension

.

Second will be in weblayout location . File will be stored as web view able version .

Usually file will be stored as

> dDocName.extension

If you want to know the original file name in UCM search result , then try to get the

> dOriginalName 
>   metadata